# What can I use to generate an interconnected graph from a series of coordinates?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting

I have a table containing latitude and longitude coordinates, and I'd like to be able to build an interconnected graph from it to use with pgRouting.

Is there an existing feature of postGIS or pgRouting I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do this, your table must contain two coordinates, one for each end of the connection. If you have this, you can do a join on the coordinates to match up endpoints and assign them matching ids. For example, imagine you have a table with the following definition:

```
create table foo (from_x float, from_y float, to_x float, to_y float);
```

Then add some id columns:

```
alter table foo add column from_id int;
alter table foo add column to_id int;
```

Then assign an initial unique id to every endpoint using a sequence:

```
create sequence id_seq;
update foo set from_id = nextval('id_seq'), to_id = nextval('id_seq');
```

Now the fun part, match up all the X and Y values and pick the lowest id of all the matches:

```
update foo f1 set from_id = (select min(id) from  
    (select from_id as id from foo f2 
      where f2.from_x= f1.from_x 
        and f2.from_y=f1.from_y 
    UNION 
     select from_id as id from foo f3 
      where f3.to_x= f1.from_x 
        and f3.to_y=f1.from_y) as bar)

update foo f1 set to_id = (select min(id) from 
    (select from_id as id from foo f2 
      where f2.from_x= f1.to_x 
        and f2.from_y=f1.to_y
    UNION
     select from_id as id from foo f3 
      where f3.to_x= f1.to_x 
        and f3.to_y=f1.to_y) as bar);
```

There is probably a more efficient way to write those last two update statements, but those should work, unless you have a very large amount of data - in which case, an index on the X and Y columns is essential:

```
create index on foo(x,y);
```

If you wanted, you could create postgis points out of all the x an y coordinates, but that isn't really necessary to build the graph. However, if your coordinates aren't perfectly equal/snapped, then you will have tochange the query to use something like:

```
@(f2.from_x - f3.from_x) < {tolerance}
```

which probably won't be indexable, so in that case, making the points, building a spatial index on them, and using st_dwithin() will likely be the best approach.